# People have the right to demand protection (for/of) their business against XYZ

Tags: exam-questions

> People have the right to demand protection **for** their business against a bandit group trying to grab it.

This sentence is from an error spotting exercise which suggests to replace *for* with *of*,  Is it correct? If yes what's the difference in the meaning of these two phrases?

Comment: Which do you think is correct, and why?  Without more detail such as any research, the question may be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I think both work.

Comment: I am a native speaker and agree with Nicholas that both are grammatical. I do feel that "of" sounds a bit more idiomatic, but I cannot articulate any rationale for that feeling.